# Converting Full Motion Video for ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-full-motion-video

I am experimenting with Full Motion Video in ArcGIS Desktop.

I used tutorial data to learn more about Full Motion Video, and then acquired UAS video from my employer.  These videos did not work, and after investigation I found that this was due to there being 12 audio streams in the videos.  After getting rid of the audio using a video conversion application to get rid of the audio, I could sort of use it.  In ArcMap I could see the video with the FMV plugin, but then realized there was no metadata in the converted video.

I would like to know how I could convert video using COTS software, while keeping the metadata, but losing the audio, and how I could extract the metadata from the original video to save it as csv, and then recreate the video using multiplexer to combine the video and csv.

I am using ArcGIS Desktop, FMV version 1.3.2

Comment: What format is the original video in? FMV supports 12 video formats: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/image-analyst/introduction-to-full-motion-video-in-arcgis-pro.htm (mostly mpeg-2 'lossy' containers)

Comment: Its a .ts (MPEG2 TS) from a UAV and not a drone.  It contained 12 audio streams which was the big issue.  Although I could convert it to MPEG-4, eliminating the audio, it lost the embedded metadata

Comment: FFMPEG option for Key, Length, Value (KLV) https://www.aeronetworks.ca/2018/05/mpeg-2-transport-streams.html also https://gwg.nga.mil/misb/docs/standards/ST0601.8.pdf

Comment: What software did you use with the UAV ?

Comment: I got the video from my employer.
I used the instructions contained in the link Mapperz provided, but there is a problem with combining the klv and video using gstreamer, even on the test video.  Something about gst_segment_to_running_time: assertion 'segment->format == format' failed